# SARIMAX prediction DECAYS to ZERO for future data and does not print correspinding futures dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm new to python and trying to forecast a time series of total sales from a store using SARIMAX. The data spans over 5-years (daily) from '2013-01-01' to '2017-08-16' . I wish to predict sales for the next 30 days ( i.e. from '2017-08-17' to '2017-09-15').

Here is the sample data, read usingthis piece of code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
import pmdarima as pmd
DF_store = pd.read_csv('Per_store_DF', index_col = "date", parse_dates = True)
DF_store
```

[sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd87F.png)

I decided to split the data into Train and Test sets - 80/20, Then use the pmdarima function to guess the optimal ARIMA model order, then train the model with SARIMAX on my endogenous data.

```
N = round((80/100)*len(DF_store))
DF_train = DF_store.iloc[:N]
DF_test = DF_store.iloc[N:]
DF_train
```

**Model Function**

```
def arima_generator(ts):
      auto_model = pmd.auto_arima(ts, start_p = 1, start_q = 1, max_p = 3, max_q = 3, m = 30,     test = "adf", trace = True)
return auto_model
```

**Apply the model function**

```
ARIMA_model = arima_generator(DF_train)
ARIMA_model.summary()
```

**Problem:**
Problems arise when I train the resulting model on my Training set and try to predict the Test data.

```
model = SARIMAX(DF_train, order =(3,0,0), seas_order = (2,0,1, 30))
result = model.fit()
result.summary()
```

**Using...**

```
start = len(DF_train)
end = len(DF_store)
predict = result.predict(start, end, dynamic = False)' (OR dynamic =True) 
DF_train.plot(legend = True, figsize=(15,10)) 
predict.plot(legend = True) predict
```

The output has no dates column
It decays to zero as shown in these pictures.
[Output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seXbP.png)

**Using "start = len(DF_test)" Only**

```
start = len(DF_test)
predict = result.predict(start, dynamic = False)
```

Gives the following output.
[Output2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJNlm.png)

**Starting Somewhere along the Train dataset**
It works to the end of the set but then decays to zero for future values as shown

```
start = len(DF_test)
end = len(DF_train)+ len(DF_test)-1
predict = result.predict(start, end, dynamic = False)
```

[Output3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mj3m.png)

#My Questions.
Summary is that my model will NOT work for any future dates.

- why is this happening?
- Is there anything i'm missing?
  I'll be gald if someone could help.
  Thanks in advance. This is the dataset:[DataFile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KYEBJDMBKdhgQk2WdPz4WpcLTi6QSjIV/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Also, `m = 30` is a strange choice for the seasonal order. Typically in a dataset like this you'd expect either weekly `m=7` or yearly `m=365` seasonality (eg. people buy more stuff in the summer, or buy more stuff on weekends.)

Comment: You shoul be able to view the file now. possible? I've also tried your suggestions (m =7 and 365 still, same results- A decay)